# How do I searh for multiple attributes using xpath in ElementTree

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

I'm looking to isolate the following values from an XML file (https://digitallibrary.un.org/search?ln=en&p=A/RES/72/266&f=&rm=&ln=en&sf=&so=d&rg=50&c=United+Nations+Digital+Library+System&of=xm&fti=0&fti=0).

```
<collection>
  <record>
    ...
    <datafield tag="993" ind1="2" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">A/C.5/72/L.22</subfield> # Value to isolate: A/C.5/72/L.22
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="993" ind1="3" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">A/72/682</subfield> # Value to isolate: A/72/682
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="993" ind1="4" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">A/72/PV.76</subfield> # Value to isolate: A/72/PV.76
    </datafield>
    ...
  </record>
  <record>
    ...
    <datafield tag="993" ind1="2" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">A/C.5/72/L.22</subfield> # Value to isolate: A/C.5/72/L.22
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="993" ind1="3" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">A/72/682</subfield> # Value to isolate: A/72/682
    </datafield>
  </record>
  ...
</collection>
```

The code I had prepared only seems to identify for each record the first item with tag 993.

```
for record in root:
  if record.find("{http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim}datafield[@tag='993']/{http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim}subfield[@code='a']") is not None:
    symbol = record.find("{http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim}datafield[@tag='993']/{http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim}subfield[@code='a']").text
    print symbol
```

Is there a way to loop to search for multiple attributes using ElementTree's xpath? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete user3091877's answer, alternate XPath option :

```
//*[name()="subfield"][@code="a"][parent::*[@tag="993"]]/text()
```

EDIT : This one will return 6 values (@tag=993 and @ind1=3) :

```
//*[name()="subfield"][parent::*[@tag="993" and @ind1="3"]]/text()
```

Comment: Thank you, E.Wiest! I have tried to use this code to isolate those values that have both `[@tag="993"]` and `[@ind1="3"]` but so far unsuccessful. Is this possible in this scenario, somehow? Many thanks for your kind consideration.

Comment: OK. So it is [@tag="993"] and [@ind1="3"] not [@tag="993"]  and [@code=a] as stated in your original post. I've edited my answer. Note :`{http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim}` is not needed with the provided XPath. Could you also explain more this part ; "to bind specific variables to the combinations "993"-"2", "993"-"3" and "993"-"4"". What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Thank you, very much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm using this script to easily find reports that are associated with UN draft resolutions, using their library records, Alfred and deanishe's alfred-workflow.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find) show that `.find()` only gets the first matching subelement. Sounds like you want `.findall()`.

The following seems to work for me:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(input_file)
root = tree.getroot()

for record in root:
    xpath = "{http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim}datafield[@tag='993']/{http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim}subfield[@code='a']"
    if record.findall(xpath) is not None:
        for symbol in record.findall(xpath):
            print symbol.text
```

Comment: Thank you, user3091877! Indeed, this gives me all matching subelements. However, the intention is to bind specific variables to the combinations "993"-"2", "993"-"3" and "994"-"4" respectively. Since not all records have all of these subelements, would there be a way to bind variables to these specific values? Thank you so much!